# How to view entity framwork connection string form visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, entity-framework-6

This could be a very simple question. But still asking because after googling for sometime nothing found. So I realize it is better to ask question here. When I define a new connection to the local ms sql server only that time I'm able to see the connection string.

[image]

How to see the connection string later. I know it is defined in web.config for app.config. But if I wan to edit it later, I think it is easy/safe to edit it such kind of wizard. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try open up the Server Explorer, rightclick your connection. There you can configure it. After that you still need to replace the respective part (accessable through the properties of the connection in the server explorer) in the App.config.

Or you expand the partial class of your ef-model with a constructor calling the base(connectionstring) constructor and use the EntityConnectionStringBuilder class to programatically assemble the connectionstring. Then you dont even need the App.Config / Web.Config entries.

Example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Apps4KidsWeb.Persistence
{
    public partial class Apps4KidsEntities : DbContext
    {
        public Apps4KidsEntities(string connectionString):base(connectionString)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

And the part to assemble the connection

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Apps4KidsWeb.Persistence
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The class connection
    /// </summary>
    public class Connection
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The connection string
        /// </summary>
        private static string connectionString = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the context.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Apps4KidsEntities GetContext()
        {
            Apps4KidsEntities result;

            if (connectionString != null)
            {
                return new Apps4KidsEntities(connectionString);
            }

            EntityConnectionStringBuilder ecsb = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();

            SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlcsb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

            ecsb.Metadata = @"res://*/DataModel.csdl|
                            res://*/DataModel.ssdl|
                            res://*/DataModel.msl";

            ecsb.Provider = "System.Data.SqlClient";

            sqlcsb.InitialCatalog = "Apps4Kids";
            sqlcsb.DataSource = "localhost";
            sqlcsb.UserID = "sa";
            sqlcsb.Password = "123user!";

            ecsb.ProviderConnectionString = sqlcsb.ToString();

            result = new Apps4KidsEntities(ecsb.ConnectionString);
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```